# Histogram with non-normalized fit line, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, probability-density

I'm trying to get a set of histograms plotted, with raw count data (non-normalized to density/pdf) and a fit line. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get a fit line plotted that ISN'T normalized by a pdf function. Is there a way to plot a non-normalized line, or a function to reverse the density calculation?  Right now, I've got the below code, which works for the normalized histogram and fit line.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x=[13.140,17.520,15.768,10.512,10.512,9.636,10.512, 9.636,11.388,7.884,7.008,7.008,9.636,11.388,7.884,7.88,16.64‌​4,42.924,17.520]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=10, normed=False, color='cornflowerblue', alpha=0.75)
(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(x)
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
l = plt.plot(bins, y, '-o', linewidth=2)
ax.set_xlabel('Millirems')
```

This is the graph i have so far, with raw count data and a normalized fit line
[image: this is the graph i have so far, with raw count data and a normalized fit line]

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you fit a pdf then you get a pdf. If you want something else then what is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this by multiplying the pdf by the total area of the histogram I think?

```
import numpy as np

l = plt.plot(bins, y * np.sum(np.diff(bins) * n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to scale the pdf by the same factor the histogram is scaled with respect to a normed one. This factor would be the area of the histogram `sum(n * np.diff(bins))`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [13.140,17.520,15.768,10.512,10.512,9.636,10.512, 9.636,11.388,7.884,7.008,7.008,9.636,11.388,7.884,7.88,16.644,42.924,17.520]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=10, normed=False, color='cornflowerblue', alpha=0.75)
(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(x)
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma) * sum(n * np.diff(bins))
plt.plot(bins, y, '-o', linewidth=2)
ax.set_xlabel('Millirems')
```

[image: histogram]